# css - how to regulate a form like inherit

Tags: html, css

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Panel</a></li>  
<li><a href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
<li><form style="display: inline;" method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
  <button type="submit">Logout</button>
 @csrf
</form></li>
</ul>
```

This is my codes. But it seems like below:

[image]

How can i do like this:

[image]

If i use `button` and `form` instead of `a` it's not tidy. If you help me i will be glad.

Comment: Apply the same styles you apply to the links also to the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin-top.
For example :

```css
margin-top: 5px;
```